# Initialize a matrix class with braces while being type safety

Tags: c++

fI have the next template of a matrix class:

```
template<typename T, int rows, int cols>
struct Matrix{
public:
    Matrix() {
        if (rows == cols)
            LoadIdentity();
    }

    T data[rows][cols];

    void LoadIdentity(){ }

    /* more methods ...  */

}
template<int rows, int cols>
using matrixf = Matrix<float, rows, cols>;
template<int rows, int cols>
using matrixd = Matrix<double, rows, cols>;
```

And i want to be able to initialize this class like:

```
void main(){
    matrixf<2, 3> m2x3 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, {4, 5, 6} };
}
```

If I try this, the compiler says:

> E0289 no instance of constructor "vian::Matrix [with T=float, rows=2, cols=3]" matches the argument list

If I remove my default constructor, I get the behaviour that I want, but I lose the posibility of having any constructor.

```
Matrix() { ... } // If I remove this, I have the behaviour I want
```

A [solution I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068882/list-initialization-for-a-matrix-class) was to create a constructor that takes an **std::initializer_list**, but if I do that, the compiler wont check if the initialier list has the right amount of arguments for a matrix of NxM size.

**Edit:** Added the LoadIdentity method so it compiles.

Comment: `void main` -> Is this C++?

Comment: What us the use case for this code?

Comment: How about `Matrix(std::array<std::array<T, cols>, rows>)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 I just tried your suggestion but I dont know if I am doing something wrong. It doesn't compile. Im trying to initialize it as: `matrixd<2, 3> m2x3 = { { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} } };` and also tried with `matrixd<2, 3> m2x3 = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} } ;`. But still same compile error.

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh, now I got it working, I have to write it like `matrixd<2, 3> m2x3{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} };`. But it still compiles if I dont specify enough arguments. E.g. `matrixd<2, 3> m2x3{ {1, 2, 3, 4} };`

Answer (score 0):

The best I could do, was to implement what @Jarod42 suggested. Create a constructor like the way he described:

> How about `Matrix(std::array<std::array<T, cols>, rows>)` ? -Jarod42

Even though it doesn't do what I wanted. I took it as an answer because it is a bit safer than what I was doing before *(having a constructor of  std::initializer_list)*. It ensures that you don't pass more arguments than it can take, but allows you to specify less. 
E.g.

```
matrixf<2, 3> m2x3{ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} }; // this compiles.
matrixf<2, 3> m2x3{ {1, 2, 3, 4} }; // this also compiles. Missing values are automatically set to 0.
```

A downside for this approach is the syntax. I wanted to initialize my matrix class by describing each row with curly braces like:

```
matrixf<2, 3> m2x3{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }; // this does not compile.
matrixf<2, 3> m2x3{ { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} } }; // this does not compile.
```

Comment: You're missing a pair of braces `matrixf<2, 3> m2x3{ {{ {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} }} };`